# How to prevent `#warning` messages from being treated as an error?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to compile introduce the `-Werror` flag in an existing codebase. One of the issues I'm encountering is that at some places `#warning` is used to display informational messages. These should not be treated as an error.

One solution would be to use `#pragma message` instead, but this does not seem to be supported by older versions of gcc. (Our build servers use gcc 4.1.2).

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Well, you're abusing `#warning`. Get rid of that, problem solved.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: What about posting an alternative?

Comment: @UncleBens: I'd need to see what it's actually doing there to suggest alternative other than "remove it". It's possible it could be replaced by something on a build system level.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus letting the build system print the message is an interesting suggestion. I'll have a look at this tomorrow.

Comment: Can't you possibly disable the flag around those `#warning`s with a `#pragma`? Might be cumbersome, but should work.

Answer (score 4):

In gcc-4.6 and above, you can use `-Wno-error=cpp`. In at least the clang released with Lion and later, you can use `-Wno-error=#warnings`. But since your build servers use an ancient gcc, you're probably out of luck there.

In general, pass -fdiagnostics-show-option to have warnings show output like:

```
test.cc:1:2: warning: #warning hello [-Wcpp]
```

which tells you a warning flag that controls the warning. In gcc >=4.6 and clang, this is the default, so knowing to pass it may not be too useful anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Locally disable effect of `-Werror` for `#warning` as follows:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wcpp"
#warning Informative message: everything is nice and good!!!
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

The benefit with this approach is that you can still induce error with `#warning` elsewhere in the code.

Comment: The above doesn't appear to work with gcc 4.1.2 - I get "warning: ignoring #pragma GCC diagnostic" and the #warning line is picked up as an error (as -Werror is defined)